# Why does my code work when run in .py file, but returns a SyntaxError in Python interpreter?

Tags: python, syntax, runtime-error

Consider this code:

```
with open("tmp", "w") as f:
    print(0)
print(1)
```

This works when saved as `bug.py` and run with `python bug.py`. But I can't copy and paste this code into a python interpreter:

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open("tmp", "w") as f:
...     print(0)
... print(1)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print(1)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Where's the syntax error?

**Edit:** This applies more generally, as in

```
if False:
    pass
pass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an extra empty line to end up your `with` statement and input the next `print` statement:

```
>>> with open('/dev/random') as fin :
...     print(0)
...                             <<--- an empty line
0
>>> print(1)
1
>>>
```

Comment: Any loop should be closed in the interactive mode by pressing <Return> twice before any other statement.

Comment: Is there any way I could have known that? ;)